# Is this an asbestos floor?

Tags: floor, asbestos

My wife and are just bought an old house (1927) and we are concerned about a floor mat in one of the bedrooms. We have been told that it could have asbestos so we would really appreciate any feedback. See the image below:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The only way to be sure is to send a sample to a testing lab. Send a sample of the adhesive too, since asbestos was sometimes mixed into that. I'm assuming this is tiles; if so you can lift one buy using a heat gun to soften the adhesive and gently lifting with a putty knife.

In most cases, encapsulating the suspect tile under a floating floor is acceptable if the stuff isn't already shedding fibers.

Comment: Other than guessing it's sheet linoleum and you'll need to cut a piece out with a utility knife, agree. The only way to know is to have it tested by a lab - you can't eyeball it and know for sure.